# Calculate worked timespans using git commits

Tags: git, bash, time

So far I got this really helpful command, which helps me to determine, when I worked on a project:

```
git log --author="MyUsername" --pretty=format:"%cd;  %h;  %s" > time.csv
```

But I'm interested, if there is a way to find out how long I have worked on the commit.
Theoretically the way to do this, would be to take the commited file with the earliest change-date in this commit and calculate the timespan between this and the commit.

Is this even possible/accurate? What would be the code to achieve this?

Comment: You can do what you described, but it wouldn't account for non-working time in between (sleeping, breaks, food, conversation, meetings) and it also would totally break once you bring rebasing into the question

Comment: I tend to commit, when I finish work, or when I go and do something else, so I can eliminate this kind of inaccuracy. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn’t possible, a commit is an atomic unit in git that tracks content – git is content oriented and has its own simple tree/blob filesystem that it uses on top of the os’ filesystem, so you cannot check an “earliest change-date in (a) commit” with git. The only thing that you can check are the commit timestamps and the time intervals between the commits, as you already do.

The only thing I can suggest is a pre-commit hook. When git executes your custom pre-commit hook you can look at all the files you are about to commit, find the earliest timestamp on your filesystem, as you’ve suggested and write this metadata somewhere. Maybe even include it with the commit. How reliable that would be … well, as mentioned in the comments, it would depend on the accounting of your extraneous physical activities :/ Maybe you can make the pre-commit hook popup an editor or a message box where you could input the number of hours spent away from working on the commit itself.